# Livereload not updating sourcemaps to less files

Tags: less, livereload, gulp-livereload

I am currently working with gulp-less workflow with livereload feature of chrome and gulp-livereload is working fine.

When I am making any changes to file, livereload refreshes the css and unfortunately it is injecting **livereload css** instead of less files.

So I have to refresh the page to show the corresponding less file which is very time consuming and made no use of livereload. 
It is totally nonsense to use livereload if I anyhow need to refresh the page to see the less sourcemap files?

Let's say I am generating custom.css file from all the less files but when I change into any partial files, livereload generates sourcemaps and updates custom.css as well in the file system but in browser what I see is only **injected css**.

See the below screenshot to get the exact issue that I am facing.Note that it also appends some version and port number also after injected css. E.g. **css/custom.css?livereload=1577164609829** for my case.

**What I am expecting to see on refresh is the corresponding less file in browser and not the injected css through the livereload.**

Has anyone faced this issue before? If yes then please help me.

**Note: Please don't advice using browser sync or any other instead of livereload.**

[image]